# Is my solution recursive? (learning recursion)

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am practicing solving problems with recursion for a class.

I am solving the problems on this site : http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-recursion-functions-exercises.php

The question I am referring to is stated : Write a JavaScript program to get the integers in range (x, y).
Example : range(2, 9)
Expected Output : [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Before looking at the solution I came up with this:

```
var range = function (start, end) {
  var result = [];
  var accumulator = start;

  var accumulate = function () {
    accumulator++;
    if (accumulator === end) {
      return;
    } else {
      result.push(accumulator);
    }
    accumulate();
  };

  accumulate();
  return result;
};
```

The solution on the site is this:

```
var range = function(start_num, end_num) 
{
  if (end_num - start_num === 2) 
  {
    return [start_num + 1];
  } 
  else 
  {
    var list = range(start_num, end_num - 1);
    list.push(end_num - 1);
    return list;
  }
};
```

Is my solution technically still recursive? I had a similar answer on a quiz recently and I was told my solution is essentially iterative.

Comment: As pointed out in some of the answers, your recursive function could be easily re-written as a loop. Good examples of recursive functions are divide and conquer algorithms, such as quicksort, where subsets of the problem are passed recursively by the function to itself as a parameter. If you are not familiar it would be worth it to look up divide and conquer algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you use recursion, you have simply written a loop in the form of recursion.

I am going to answer this from the purely academical standpoint. If you want to avoid the intermediate state (`result`) and use purely functional constructs, I would write it like this

```
function range(start, end) {
  function recRange(current, end) {
    if (current > end)
      return [];
    return [current].concat(recRange(current + 1, end));
  }
  return recRange(start + 1, end - 1);
}
console.log(range(2, 9));
// [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

If you see here, we create a new function within the `range` function, which recursively creates a new array on every iteration (remember: this is not highly performant code, you can simply use loops and be done with this problem efficiently).

The base condition of the recursion is `current < end`. Once that is met, the recursion stops and an empty array is returned. In all the levels, a new array with the `current` value is concatenated with the result of the recursive call. So, the evaluation of the calls are roughly understood like this

```
[3].concat(recRange(3 + 1, end));
[3].concat([4].concat(recRange(4 + 1, end)));
...
```

at the end, when the recursion unwinds, the values will be like this

```
[3].concat([4].concat([5].concat([6].concat([7].concat([8].concat([]))))))
[3].concat([4].concat([5].concat([6].concat([7].concat([8])))))
[3].concat([4].concat([5].concat([6].concat([7, 8]))))
[3].concat([4].concat([5].concat([6, 7, 8])))
[3].concat([4].concat([5, 6, 7, 8]))
[3].concat([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

and that will be returned as the result.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my solution technically still recursive?

Yes.  You're using tail recursion; however, since no arguments are being passed to accumulate() I  can see why someone may say it's essentially iterative.  You could easily replace your recursive call with a loop.  Recursive algorithms typically leverage the stack.

Because of Javascript's closures, it is harder to understand the concept of recursion in Javascript compared to other languages like C++ or Java or C#.

To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.   :)

Answer (score 2):

To make your solution recursive, it should **return some value** and somehow **combine the result of the recursive call** to form the return value of the original call.

Let me illustrate that with an example, by modifying your solution:

```
var range = function (start, end) {

  var accumulate = function (accumulator) {
    if (accumulator === end - 1) {
      return [accumulator];  // Stop condition 
    } else {
      // Recursive block
      var result = accumulate(accumulator+1);  // recursive call
      result.unshift(accumulator);  // combine result
      return result
    }
  };

  return accumulate(start);
};
```

The modified accumulate function will return a one-element list for the stop condition, the simplest case it handles, where accumulator reaches the last value to return.

In the example `range(2,9)`, the stop condition will return `[8]`.

Then in the caller, the recursive block

```
      var result = accumulate(accumulator+1);
      result.unshift(accumulator);
      return result
```

will take the list `[8]`, and preprend the current value of `accumulator` (`7`), so it'll return `[7,8]`.

...and the caller of `accumulator(7)`, will receive `[7,8]` and preprend the value `6` to the list, to return `[6,7,8]`.

At the end, the original call to `accumulator(2)` will generate the expected result `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.